# Google Site Search Not Passing Results to Google Search Account

Tags: search, google-analytics

Please consider the following (Issue is, the results of the Google Search on our page is not registering within our Google Analytics Account):

**HTML FORM:**

```
    <div style="float:right; margin-right:12px;">
    <form id="cse-search-box" name="srchfrm" action="http://google.com/cse" target="_blank" onsubmit="validatesearch()">
        <input value="999999999999999999999:srraaaaaaaa" name="cx" type="hidden"/>
        <input id="q" name="q" type="text" onKeyPress="return submitenter(this,event)" placeholder="Search"/>
        <a href="javascript:;" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('go','','/btn_go_on.gif',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
        <input type="image" src="/btn_go.gif" alt="Go" width="20" height="21" border="0" align="top" id="go"/>
        <input value="UTF-8" name="ie" type="hidden"/>    
    </form> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('search', '1');
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    google.search.CustomSearchControl.attachAutoCompletion(
      '999999999999999999999:srraaaaaaaa',
      document.getElementById('q'),
      'cse-search-box');
  });
</script>
```

**URL ON EXECUTING A SEARCH:**

```
http://www.google.com/cse?cx=999999999999999999999:srraaaaaaaa&q=test+search&x=12&y=11&ie=UTF-8&oq=&gs_l=#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=test%20search&gsc.page=1
```

**QUERY PARAMETERS BEING USED:**

```
q
query (I read in another post to try this)
```

Thank you for all the help in advance!

Comment: OK, the obvious question: you did set up search tracking in GA, right? http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95142

Comment: @EstoyOcupado Yes, all of the account aspects have been set up. Turned on the feature and set up the query parameters...etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing:

```
action="http://google.com/cse"
```

within,

```
<form id="cse-search-box" name="srchfrm" action="http://google.com/cse" target="_blank" onsubmit="validatesearch()">
```

to redirect to a page within the website, this resolved the issue.

Working code:

```
<div style="float:right; margin-right:12px;">
    <form id="searchbox_99999999999999999999:srraaaaaaaa" name="srchfrm" action="/search" target="_self" onsubmit="validatesearch()">
        <input value="99999999999999999999:srraaaaaaaa" name="cx" type="hidden"/>
        <input id="q" name="q" autocomplete="off" type="text" onKeyPress="return submitenter(this,event)" placeholder="Search"/>
        <input name="ie" value="UTF-8" type="hidden"/>
        <a href="javascript:;" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('go','','/btn_go_on.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
        <input type="image" src="/btn_go.png" alt="Go" width="20" height="21" border="0" align="top" id="go"/> 
    </form> 
</div>
```

The Search Page itself has the following code as per Google documentation:

HEAD:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '99999999999999999999:srraaaaaaaa';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
```

BODY:

```
<gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
```